# Correct way to implement a toolbar in activity using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I have a problem adding a toolbar to my app. I started with an empty activity. Using this tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up and this tutorial https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DMkzIOLppf4.

However, although `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`
is added to the dependencies in build.gradle (Module:app), using the support library does not seem to work as I get following error:

```
package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

I already found that this might be due to enabled androidx and indeed, I found

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in gradle.properties. However, setting both to false gives me the following error:

`ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-24:19 to override.`

But to be honest, I do not know what to do with that error message...

Could you tell me what's the correct way to add a toolbar. And in case it is with androidx enabled, could you point me to tutorial? And the other way around, in case it is via android.support.v7.widget, what do I have to do to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion of adding tools:replace tag inside the application tag of manifest?

Comment: Tried to, but then it says "Build failed with an exception" because of that: Präfix "tools" für Attribut "tools:replace", das mit Elementtyp "application" verknüpft ist, ist nicht gebunden (tools which is linked to application is not bound)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the solution.
It is not necessary to implement`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`. Instead use

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

In the java-File you need to add

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
```

and set up the toolbar with

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

However, I would be glad if someone more experienced could verify this solution to be correct.